# How to determine if a circuit breaker has GFCI

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, code-compliance, gfci

I recently discovered none of the grounds in the three-prong outlets in my house are connected to anything.  AFAICT the only way this is allowed without GFCI outlets is to have GFCI circuit breakers and then a sticker on the outlets with "no equipment ground."

Is there anything on the circuit breakers that indicates GFCI, generally?

Comment: Many people who's homes are already ungrounded will just change out the outlet so that their devices can be plugged in. The item isn't grounded or safe, but it's basically like using one of those two-prong adapters. --- What I'm saying is that you shouldn't be surprised if it's unprotected.

Comment: Note that you can also use GFCI outlets, and daisy-chain from the load side of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They'll typically have a test button and a pigtail that attaches to the neutral bus.

[image]
<sup>Image courtesy of Amazon.com. Not an endorsement of the pictured product or vendor.</sup>